# Why user defined @javax.persistence.Converter isn't recognized by hibernate when mapping the entity field to database column

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have the following Entity containing a field of Enum type:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INPUT_DATA")
public class InputDataEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "INPUT_DATA_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "INPUT_DATA_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "INPUT_DATA_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIELD1", nullable = false)
    private String field1;

    @Column(name = "FIELD2", nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = Type.Converter.class)
    private Type field2;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The Enum type looks like:

```
public enum Type {

    ENUM_ITEM_1("item1"),
    // more items
    ENUM_ITEM_N("itemN");

    private String code;

    private Type(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public static Type fromString(String name) {
        switch (name) {
            case "item1":
                return ENUM_ITEM_1;
            // more cases
            case "itemN":
                return ENUM_ITEM_N;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong value for Type");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return code;
    }

    @javax.persistence.Converter
    public static class Converter implements AttributeConverter<Type, String> {
       @Override
        public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Type attribute) {
            return attribute.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Type convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
            return Type.fromString(s);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that hibernate doesn't recognize my ***Converter*** when I want to fetch data from the database.

I've also tried:

- @Embedded and @Embeddable but with no luck.
- @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) but again with no luck.

**My question is:**
how to make hibernate to recognize my converter when converting the appropriate field?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of hibernate and jpa do you use ?

Comment: hibernate - 4.3.7 and jpa 2.1 - 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up by implementing a StringValuedEnum interface and its relevant reflector and type class by implementing EnhancedUserType, ParameterizedType as it was described [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/Java5StringValuedEnumUserType).

This helped me to properly store into and retrieve from DB data corresponding to user defined enum types, although the questions with converters remains still open. If someday a proper answer will be given, that will be very appreciated.